# How to do left join without duplicates rows sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to perform join between two tables based on ID (i need all the columns from the first table and only one column from the right table), for some reasons the join create duplicate rows on the created table is much bigger than the left table.
for example:

**Lead Table:**

```
|lead_id  |owner   |status
----------------------------
|10002    |Jhon    |won
|10003    |David   |lost
|10004    |Roy     |open
```

**Activity Table:**

```
|lead_id  |owner   |activity
----------------------------
|10002    |Jhon    |sales
|10002    |Jhon    |sales
|10003    |David   |marketing 
|10004    |Roy     |manager
|10004    |Roy     |manager
```

My required result is :

```
|lead_id |owner |activity  |status
----------------------------------
|10002   |Jhon  |sales     |won
|10003   |David |marketing |lost
|10004   |Roy   |manager   |open
```

instead, I am getting a table with more rows than "Lead Table" have
My code is:

```
SELECT
      d.*,
      a."activity" as "activity type"
FROM  "Deals Table" d
LEFT JOIN "Activity Table" a ON d."lead_id"  = a."lead_id"
```

Thanks !!

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please tag only the one database that you are running.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT`. However, be careful when using it since it may hide duplicates you actually want to capture. It also might hide the fact your join condition is too broad.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      d.*,
      a."activity" as "activity type"
FROM  "Deals Table" d
LEFT JOIN "Activity Table" a ON d."lead_id"  = a."lead_id"
```

Comment: I tried to use distinct the new table its with lest rows now but still there are more rows.. my join table Is with 71000 rows and the left table with 51000 rows , before the distinct it was 84000.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      d.*,
      a."activity" as "activity type"
FROM  "Deals Table" d
LEFT JOIN (
select distinct lead_id  ,owner   ,activity
from "Activity Table" 
) as a
ON d."lead_id"  = a."lead_id"
```

Comment: I tried to use distinct the new table its with lest rows now but still there are more rows.. my join table Is with 71000 rows and the left table with 51000 rows , before the distinct it was 84000.

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct

```
SELECT distinct
      d.lead_id,
      d.owner,
      d.status,
      a."activity" as "activity type"
FROM  "Deals Table" d
LEFT JOIN "Activity Table" a ON d."lead_id"  = a."lead_id"  ;
```